# Area of infinite number of points

Tags: geometry, area

Let's say I have a set $S$ of points in $\mathbb{R} ^2$, and I was able to find a bijection from $S$ to the unit disk. Can I say that the area of points in $S$ is $\pi$? 
I doubt it.. so my alternative question is, what additional constraints on $S$ do I need in order to prove that?

Comment: One circle is the same as another, as sets anyway.  Nothing special about radius $1$.  For that matter, the points in the disk are in bijection with the points in the entire plane.

Comment: It's not constraints on $S$ that you need - you probably need to add constraints on the bijection between $S$ and the unit circle. *But you can also add a constraint on $S$ that it has area $\pi$.*

Comment: @WhatsUp Like what? For example if $S$ is made up of finitely many "chunks", would I be able to conclude that? Any other conditions spring to mind? Thanks

Comment: Like if the bijection preserves area... You probably cannot get much useful description.

Answer (score 2):

Of course not: consider the function from the unit disk $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\mid x^2+y^2\leq1\}$ to the disk of radius $2$, $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\mid x^2+y^2\leq 4\}$, given by $(x,y)\mapsto(2x,2y)$. Geometrically this magnifies the unit disk by a factor of $2$, which is evidently a bijection, but doesn't conserve the area. If you require that the map is an [*isometry*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometry) (i.e. it preserves distances), then it is true that area is conserved.

Answer (score 0):

Just a bijection? If so, you can at best say that $S$ has the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$. If you have more (continuous), you can say more.